# TS2339: property height does not exist on '{}', when destructuring possibly undefined object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to destructure an optional type prop like this:

```
export interface Props {
  style: object;
}

const MyComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ style }) => {
  const { width, height, ...newStyle } = style || {};
```

But I get a typescript warning:

```
TS2339: Property 'width' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Did you not expect that? If the style isn't defined, you're destructing an object that indeed has neither width nor height. And could you not have a more specific type than object to begin with?

Comment: How do I define style in the interface to evade this warning?

Comment: Well what props *does* style have? Beyond the two you show here we can't tell you that. Also, whatever's in the interface, your default should match too. You don't want to *"evade"* the warning, TypeScript is helpfully telling you **your code doesn't make sense**.

Comment: I edited the question. It's a standard React Native prop. It's a style. All object properties are optional.

Comment: IIRC there's more than one style type even in the defaults; View and Text have different styles, for example. But if all the props are optional, then maybe it *doesn't* have width and height.

Comment: Correct. It may not have width, or height, and in that case I want them to destructure to undefined.

Comment: With standard style declaration (not related to react native) would be `Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>`

Comment: Then if `style` had the right type to begin with, you'd be OK: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=7&ssc=14&pln=5&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAyqA20C8UDeAoKWoGMD28eATgPwBcUAzsEQJYB2A5gNybYAWEtj7w5U9AK4BbAEYQirbFADutACbB2-IWImsAvunQAzQfRzBaeerjzCwJiPWAAKMETxhKFVFQQR+cEIigaAlGhsWPj01GhQnNy8ADSyCkpxAHQpeEoSflAoDk6USdQ+0AA+RWgamuhAA

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted? And why without further comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared `style` as simply `object`, which also doesn't have `width` or `height`.

Define `style` with the appropriate type information. For instance, if this is the `style` property of HTML elements, the correct type is `CSSStyleDeclaration`:

```
export interface Props {
    style: CSSStyleDeclaration;
}

const MyComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ style }) => {
    const { width, height, ...newStyle } = style || {};
    // ...
};
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?jsx=2&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocpAD0ljmADsYkpN0k4AFHMAZzgBvcnDh8YATwA2SAFxwAwgGUVkmQBEkaKSigoYwCIwoBfSmiPi4AWQkLckRkmbzk6GADoAYgoA8PCH4APjgAXjgACkExNU4TAEowkOFRUQtGK2iAd2AAExgACwAaOAKkYABzApgSjzqnLKVYuBMwmOlOAB9OoRMKVLgiGABXKEY4X1zgADc4AHog01IgA).

But if it's your own `style` information, define a type for it with `width` and `height`, and use that.

---

In comments you've clarified that you're using React Native (not React on browsers) and that:

> It may not have width, or height, and in that case I want them to destructure to undefined.

That would be:

```
interface Props {
    style: {
        width?: number;
        height?: number;
    }
}
```

...at a minimum. The fact you're collecting other properties into `newStyle` suggests you may need more than that. The fact you're applying a default suggests that `style` itself should be marked optional (`?`).

Comment: Thanks. For future reference, how and where could I have found that I needed `CSSStyleDeclaration`. Are those listed somewhere for React Native? (BTW in my case I needed `ViewStyle`).

Comment: @raarts - I'm afraid I don't know the answer for React Native. For DOM stuff, I looked at what the declared type of `style` on `HTMLElement` was using the TypeScript playground. :-)